# How to have multiple Struts2 interceptors which call `invocation.invoke()`?

Tags: java, struts2, struts2-interceptors

Suppose there are multiple nested interceptors within a struts 2 action:

- foo

  - bar

    - baz

each of the interceptors is doing the following in their `intercept()` method

```
String result = invocation.invoke();
return result;
```

When `invocation.invoke()` is called, will this call the `intercept()` method of the next interceptor in the queue, or will it actually call the `action.execute()` method?

E.g if `foo` does `invocation.invoke()`, will this call `bar.intercept()` or will it actually call `action.execute()`?

If the latter, then what can I do to have `bar.intercept()` or `baz.intercept()` (if called from bar interceptor) be called before `action.execute()`, i.e so all interceptors are run before `action.execute()` is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the interceptors in the stack will be called before the `action.execute()` method is executed. In this case, the following will be the order.

1. `foo.intercept()`
2. `bar.intercept()`
3. `baz.intercept()`
4. `action.execute()`

Comment: It seems you are right, the [documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionInvocation.html#invoke()) for `invoke()` says: `Invokes the next step..If there are more Interceptors, this will call the next one. If Interceptors choose not to short-circuit ActionInvocation processing and return their own return code, they will call invoke() to allow the next Interceptor to execute. If there are no more Interceptors to be applied, the Action is executed. If the ActionProxy getExecuteResult() method returns true, the Result is also executed.`

Answer (score 2):

`Action` executes only once. All the `Interceptors` have a chance to fire twice: once for *pre-processing* (before calling `invoke()`) and the other for *post-processing* (after calling `invoke()`).

So, in your example here's what happens:

```
foo calls invoke() -> calls bar#intercept()
bar calls invoke() -> calls baz#intercept()
baz calls invoke() -> calls action#execute()

action#execute() returns -> baz executes lines after invoke()
baz#intercept() returns -> bar executes lines after invoke()
bar#intercept() returns -> foo executes lines after invoke()
```

Please, note that the `Interceptors` never call each other directly. All the calls have to go through the `Struts 2` framework. That's why `invoke()` is called on the `ActionInvocation` object which pretty much orchestrates this whole flow.